# Cron Job in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, cron, task, jobs

I want to automate a task quarterly in a year.

Task should execute

- Jan 1st
- April 1st
- July 1st
- October 1st
- etc

As I tried `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 6 1 1/3 ?")` in Spring Boot application but its not working currently and mail didn't trigger quarterly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`@scheduled(cron = "0 0 6 1 */3 *")`

So read the first day of each 3 month at 6:00

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

@scheduled(cron ="0 0 0 1 JAN,APR,JUL,OCT ? *")

Next execution:

- Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 UTC 2020
- Thu Oct 01 00:00:00 UTC 2020
- Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 2021
- Thu Apr 01 00:00:00 UTC 2021
- Thu Jul 01 00:00:00 UTC 2021
- Fri Oct 01 00:00:00 UTC 2021
- Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 2022
- Fri Apr 01 00:00:00 UTC 2022
- Fri Jul 01 00:00:00 UTC 2022
- Sat Oct 01 00:00:00 UTC 2022

Comment: Thanks for response...can you share how you are able to test above scheduler.Seems like my code block never fire during mentioned particular time.

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html visit this site it will give more insight. Please upvote. If you found the answer is useful.